# wine needs Mono but does not install it

Tags: software-installation, wine, downloads, mono

Just installed the latest wine on 16.04 (all updated+upgraded) and tried to run a windows installer "wine nn4me.exe" and it showed

"...needs .NET, but it is better to use ... Mono ..."

and an "Install" button.

I clicked that and nothing happened. Waited five minutes, still no activity on the progress-bar nor on the modem/router LEDs.

Thought it might be a "sudo" thing so tried "sudo wine nn4me.exe" and got a message "you don't own wine"

How do I get it to install Mono **and** my program?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could [ask the Wine folks](https://forum.winehq.org/) to add Mono to their package, but until then, https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin shows how to add it. for 16.04:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF  
sudo apt install apt-transport-https  
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Great, thanks. It got Mono loaded but has not made any difference to the install process. Looks like I have to use a VM with win in it.

Comment: If I answered the question you asked, and my answer is the best available, please click on the checkmark on the left side of the answer to show that for the benefit of other folks.